# I am having trouble creating a 3-Dimensional Double Pendulum animation

Tags: python, animation, physics, pendulum

I am having trouble and I assume it is with the equations of motion but I can't seem to get them right. The force also does not seem to be applying in the correct direction and I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Double pendulum parameters
L1 = 1.0 # Length of line1, from the stationary point to m1
L2 = 0.5 # Length of line2, from m1 to m2
m1 = 1.0 # The first mass
m2 = 2.0 # The second mass
g = 9.81 # Gravity of course

# Initial conditions
theta1_0 = np.pi / 2.0
theta2_0 = np.pi / 2.0
omega1_0 = 0.0
omega2_0 = 0.0
y1_0 = 0.0
y2_0 = 0.0
y3_0 = 0.0

# Time range and step size
t_start = 0.0
t_end = 50.0
dt = 0.05 #Time step
t = np.arange(t_start, t_end, dt)

# Solve the double pendulum equations of motion
def double_pendulum(t, y, L1, L2, m1, m2, g):
    theta1, omega1, theta2, omega2, y1, y2, y3 = y

    # Equations of motion
    theta1_dot = omega1
    omega1_dot = (-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * np.sin(theta1) - m2 * g * np.sin(theta1 - 2 * theta2) - 2 *
                 np.sin(theta1 - theta2) * m2 * (omega2 ** 2 * L2 + omega1 ** 2 * L1 * np.cos(theta1 - theta2))) / \
                (L1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * np.cos(2 * theta1 - 2 * theta2)))

    theta2_dot = omega2
    omega2_dot = (2 * np.sin(theta1 - theta2) * (omega1 ** 2 * L1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * np.cos(theta1) +
                                                omega2 ** 2 * L2 * m2 * np.cos(theta1 - theta2))) / \
                (L2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * np.cos(2 * theta1 - 2 * theta2)))

    y1_dot = 0.0  # Stationary point
    y2_dot = omega1 * np.sin(theta1) * L1 + omega2 * np.sin(theta2) * L2
    y3_dot = omega2 * np.sin(theta2) * L2

    return [theta1_dot, omega1_dot, theta2_dot, omega2_dot, y1_dot, y2_dot, y3_dot]

# Solve the initial value problem
sol = solve_ivp(double_pendulum, [t_start, t_end], [theta1_0, omega1_0, theta2_0, omega2_0, y1_0, y2_0, y3_0],
                args=(L1, L2, m1, m2, g), t_eval=t)

# Extract the solution
theta1, omega1, theta2, omega2, y1, y2, y3 = sol.y


# Convert to Cartesian coordinates
x1 = L1 * np.sin(theta1)
y1 = L1 * np.cos(theta1)
z1 = -L1 * np.sin(y1)

x2 = x1 + L2 * np.sin(theta2)
y2 = y1 + L2 * np.cos(theta2)
z2 = z1 - L2 * np.sin(y2)

# Create the figure and axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('Double Pendulum Animation')

# Initialize the lines
line1, = ax.plot([], [], [], 'o-', color='blue', lw=2)  # Line for the first arm
line2, = ax.plot([], [], [], 'o-', color='green', lw=2)  # Line for the second arm
line_trace, = ax.plot([], [], [], color='red', lw=1)  # Line trace for m2

# Animation update function
def update_animation(i):
    # Update the lines
    line1.set_data([0, x1[i]], [0, y1[i]])
    line1.set_3d_properties([0, z1[i]])
    line2.set_data([x1[i], x2[i]], [y1[i], y2[i]])
    line2.set_3d_properties([z1[i], z2[i]])

    # Update the line trace for m2
    line_trace.set_data(x2[:i+1], y2[:i+1])
    line_trace.set_3d_properties(z2[:i+1])

    return line1, line2, line_trace

# Create the animation
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update_animation, frames=len(t), interval=50, blit=True)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The motion appear chaotic but it does not form the "bowl" that most animations produce. It's almost like there's a limit at x=0 where the mass cannot cross there. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here stems in principle from the fact that you have the wrong equations of motion. To start with, you need different parameters to describe the state. I'm not sure what the `y1`, `y2`, and `y3` variables are intended for, but they're unused in showing the position of the double pendulum.

The position of a single pendulum in 3 dimensions requires 2 parameters, as a point on the surface of a sphere. You can use `theta` and `phi` for this. Following that, to describe the current state of the system, you need to use `theta_dot` and `phi_dot`. I suggest trying to implement this before moving to the more difficult case of a double-pendulum. To find the equations of motion, check here: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/explore/michaelspages/documentation/Spherical

Here's some code that produces a single pendulum:

> ```
> # Single pendulum parameters
>  L = 1.0
>  m = 1.0
>  g = 9.81
>
>  # Initial conditions
>  theta_0 = np.pi/2.0
>  phi_0 = 0.0
>  theta_dot_0 = 0.0
>  phi_dot_0 = np.pi/3.0
>
>  # Time range and step size
>  t_start = 0.0
>  t_end = 50.0
>  dt = 0.05 #Time step
>  t = np.arange(t_start, t_end, dt)
>
>  # Solve the double pendulum equations of motion
>  def single_pendulum(t, y, L, m, g):
>      theta, phi, theta_dot, phi_dot = y
>
>      # Equations of motion
>      theta_ddot = (phi_dot ** 2 * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(theta)) - ((m * g/L) * np.sin(theta))
>
>      phi_ddot = -2.0 * phi_dot * theta_dot / np.tan(theta)
>
>      return [theta_dot, phi_dot, theta_ddot, phi_ddot]
>
>  # Solve the initial value problem
>  sol = solve_ivp(single_pendulum, [t_start, t_end], [theta_0, theta_dot_0, phi_0, phi_dot_0],
>                  args=(L, m, g), t_eval=t)
>
>  # Extract the solution
>  theta, phi, theta_dot, phi_dot = sol.y
>
>  # Convert to Cartesian coordinates
>  x1 = L * np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
>  y1 = L * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
>  z1 = L * np.cos(theta)
> ```

Similarly, for a double pendulum, you need two sets of spherical coordinates, one for the first branch and one for the second. So in total, you'll need eight variables to describe the state:

1. `theta1`
2. `phi1`
3. `theta2`
4. `phi2`
5. `theta1_dot`
6. `phi1_dot`
7. `theta2_dot`
8. `phi2_dot`

And then you'll need to use Lagrangian mechanics to solve for the equations of motion.

(I may return to this answer and find the equations of motion, but it's incredibly tedious to do the math. Also, I have been unable to find anyone who has gone through the derivation.)